# Button to the table view controller and do filter functions

Tags: ios, xcode

Forgive me that I am a new programmer and not familiar with the coding 
So my question is I want to make a button in Viewcontroller1 which trigger actions to go to another view controller (which I did it), and simutaneously call the function(filtering table view) of TutorListTableViewController (in another class)

I am not certain that whether calling the function of another class is the right way to go. If yes, I still cannot call that function successfully.
Any help is much appreciated! The error shown like this:

**Button action of ViewController1**

```
@IBAction func englishGO(_ sender: Any) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    TutorListViewController.observeEnglishCases()
}
```

**Function of TutorListTableViewController**

```
func observeEnglishCases(){
    let casesRef = Database.database().reference().child("cases")
    let queryRef = casesRef.child("school").queryEqual(toValue: "Ling")
    queryRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        var tempPosts = [Case]()


        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let name = dict["name"] as? String,
                let gender = dict["gender"] as? String,
                let school = dict["school"] as? String,
                let year = dict["year"] as? String,
                let major = dict["major"] as? String,
                let tutorsubject = dict["tutorsubject"] as? String,
                let tutoryear = dict["tutoryear"] as? String,
                let tutorperformance = dict["tutorperformance"] as? String,
                let region = dict["region"] as? String,
                let minimumprice = dict["minimumprice"] as? String,
                let thingtospeak = dict["thingtospeak"] as? String,
                let photoURL = dict["photoURL"] as? String,
                let url = URL(string:photoURL){
                let caser = Case(name: name, gender: gender, school: school, year: year, major: major, tutorsubject: tutorsubject, tutoryear: tutoryear, tutorperformance: tutorperformance, region: region, minimumprice: minimumprice, thingtospeak: thingtospeak, photoURL: url)
                tempPosts.insert(caser, at:0)
            }
        }
        self.cases = tempPosts
        self.tutorCasesCollectionView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Comment: welcome in SO world. Please read how to user Delegate, Notification or Blocks. You can use the above three for calling a function from one class to another.

Comment: Why dont you call observeEnglish in the TutorListTableViewController class ?

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi Thank you for your reply. I just want to call that function when the button in the ViewController1 is pressed. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already pointed out, you need to read on how to pass information around. (delegates, notifications, blocks) To give you a general idea for later:

- `ViewController1` could have a delegate to tell someone that "englishGO" was tapped
- that someone must have a reference to `TutorListViewController` instance and when an "englishGO" tap is detected, it calls `observeEnglishCases()` on that instance

However, within your current implementation, this might work:

```
@IBAction func englishGO(_ sender: Any) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    (self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as? TutorListViewController)?. observeEnglishCases()
}
```

`observeEnglishCases()` is an instance method and must be called as such. By writing `TutorListViewController.observeEnglishCases()` you've called a class method which probably does not exist in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution could be this:

In the viewDidLoad method of TutorListViewController call the observeEnglishCases if the index has the right value:

E.g.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if selectedIndex == 1 {
        observeEnglishCases()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to call that function in the button action? As the selectedIndex1 is exactly the TutorListViewController

Comment: I think instead of doing this, you could present/push the TutorListViewController and then, in it's viewDidLoad method call your method observeEnglishCases